# Dynamic failureRedirect with passport.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

This is my login function atm:

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/login?error=1"
}), function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(req.body.url || "/");
});
```

I need to put the req.body.url inside the failureRedirect url, so it should looks like:

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
    failureRedirect: "/login?error=1&url=" + (req.body.url || "/")
}), function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(req.body.url || "/");
});
```

It can't work because the req variable is inited only inside the callback of `post`... how can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Custom Callbacks](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate#custom-callback) to dynamically generate callbacks urls, as the req object is available inside them.

Comment: Custom Callbacks url [http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate#custom-callback] shared 
in this answer does not exists

Comment: The answer is outdated (2014, then updated in 2016) - I suggest you to read the up to date documentation: https://www.passportjs.org/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is cleaner way to do so, but this is any easy workaround:

```
app.post(
    "/login",
    function (req, res, next) {
        const callback = passport.authenticate("local", {failureRedirect: "/login?error=1&url=" + (req.body.url || "/"});
        return callback(req, res, next);
    },
    function (req, res) {
        res.redirect(req.body.url || "/");
    }
);
```

Instead of immediately using the middleware returned by the call to `passport.authenticate()`, you wrap it so that you can make use of `req, res, next`.