# Re-authentication problem with passport.js after logout

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, passport.js

I have an application federated with Azure AD. Users from B2C and B2B are able to sign in to this application at first time. If we click sign out and try to sign in again, the sign in will fail.

App uses passport.js and OIDC strategy for login. While attempting to re-authenticate via passport.authenticate(..) , it gets redirected to URL defined as failureRedirect. 
**Please note, if I try after sometime say 10-15 mins, login works fine as expected. It fails intermittently.

Could you please let me know if anyone have seen this similar issue.
I am using "passport version 0.4.0"

Let me know if any information is required.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Custom Callbacks](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate#custom-callback) to dynamically generate callbacks urls and avoid this issue.

```
    app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    // Redirect if it fails
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      // Redirect if it succeeds
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

There are a good number of users on Stackoverflow who have asked this exact same question so I would suggest taking a look at some of these questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808827/dynamic-failureredirect-with-passport-js), this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31407425/passport-js-always-executing-failureredirect), and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858699/nodejs-and-passportjs-redirect-middleware-after-passport-authenticate-not-being)) if you haven't done so already.

Please also ensure that the Reply URL/RedirectURI in your code matches what you have in your App Registration in Azure AD.